# Magento 2 optionally ask for gender in checkout (billing and shipping)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, orders, customer

I go to

> Stores > MyStore > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options

There I set `Show Gender` to `optional`.

I expect that a gender field would appear on the checkout shipping and billing address that the customer can optionally check.
But nothing appears.

On the database I can see that the `sales_order` has a field `customer_gender`. So I suspect there should be a way to activate the field.

How do I insert a gender field on the checkout shipping and billing addresses?

Comment: Are you using a custom checkout or standard Magento's?

Comment: I'm using my own theme with a standard checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature request / open issue on this topic since it was supported in m1 but got lost in m2:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14509